# While pushing a docker container to Azure Container Registry, it shows, "no basic auth credentials" error and stops

Tags: windows, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I am trying to push a docker container created locally on my machine while executing docker push command, it exits with error saying "no basic auth credentials". I have already logged in to azure container registry created through the portal.

```
The push refers to repository [********.azurecr.io/*******]
6d4b0f494716: Preparing
20c543670a9f: Preparing
17165e287a94: Preparing
4b006b08d3ae: Preparing
672ed6bd08c2: Preparing
3a8d6d9a8fd8: Waiting
3cf5be92ce58: Waiting
e987182e7e0b: Waiting
f1043e044fa7: Waiting
58986674d8ad: Waiting
1eeb10e1d5d0: Waiting
89f263bde6fb: Waiting
f358be10862c: Waiting
no basic auth credentials
```

Comment: What command do you use to log in the registry and push the image?

Comment: try login in with below command 
`docker login yourregistry.azurecr.io` followed by your secret.
and if you are pulling, updating image/service make sure to add a param

`--with-registry-auth`

Comment: @KavyeshShah Thanks for the suggestion. But the issue is resolved.

Comment: @CharlesXu i used docker login <azurecr-login-server>

Comment: @nr75 how did you solve the issue?

Comment: @AaronUllal for me it was basically an internet issue.